# Get inside of square brackets in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this string.

```
"ascascascasc[xx]asdasdasdasd[yy]qweqweqwe"
```

I want to get strings inside brackets. Like this;

```
"xx", "yy"
```

I have tried this but it did not work:

```
a = "ascascascasc[xx]asdasdasdasd[yy]qweqweqwe"
listinside = []
for i in range(a.count("[")):
    listinside.append(a[a.index("["):a.index("]")])
print (listinside)
```

Output:

```
['[xx', '[xx']
```

Comment: What's your reasoning behind using `count()`? What were you counting? Have you heard of regular expressions? They are most likely what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need count , you can use regex , [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) can do it :

```
>>> s="ascascascasc[xx]asdasdasdasd[yy]qweqweqwe"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]',s)
['xx', 'yy']
```

> `\[` matches the character [ literally
>
> `*?` matches Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
>
> `\]` matches the character ] literally

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rB0wY6/1)

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome. But why they rate negative my post. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @ you're welcome , because SO in not  *do my homework for me* site , and you need to put your code that you had before , as i see you say that you used count . so i give answer . with this probability that you are not aware from roles ! now its better to add your code that you tried so far .

Comment: I've edited my question with my trying. Hope negatives will gone lol. By the way it's not for my homework, it's for my own personel software project.